# Xamarin build fails to load assembly I'm not even referencing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project loaded in VS 2017. When I build the project I get error: `Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?`

`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` is not referenced by this project, i.e. it's not under `References`, nor `packages.config`. It's not listed in Nuget Package Manager's list of installed packages.

- How can I figure out why the build is trying to load that assembly?
- Why is the build even trying to load assemblies, shouldn't that be the responsability of the application, not of the build? (Not saying it does, but an app may "know" how to load its assemblies using a custom `ResolveEventHandler`, the build can't "know" that.)

Comment: Try running update-package -reinstall in nuget console

Comment: In preparing the app bundle, the "build" has to be able to access all the referenced assemblies and their dependancies to include them, either as extra data during fast debug deploys, using the Mono Linker, bundling an apk, AOTing, etc.. I would *assume* you are referencing a project (directly or via a dependancy) that uses `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` and thus Jwt, thus add the package it to your `Xamarin.Android` project.

Comment: @SushiHangover what if your project references an assembly A1 that embeds another assembly A2. If the "build" is trying to be smart by opening A1 to see what it depends on, sees A2, then tries to access A2, it would fail because only A1 "knows" where A2 is (perhaps inlined as a long embedded string, perhaps as a resource file). How is my project supposed to "teach" the build not to try to access A2?

Comment: @mipnw It wouldn't, if A2 is a hard reference within A1, then it needs to be available to be processed. What is the MSBuild Task name that is faulting?

Comment: @SushiHangover: Ok. Not sure about the task name, will go dig that up

Comment: @mipnw by chance you use some antivirus ?, because my antivirus (Bitdefender) blocked me access to some processes during the compilation and some errors like that appeared.